# Problem loading WMS layer from BCgov into QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I can't seem to get this layer to show up in QGIS. Is anyone else able to load this WMS layer from the BCgov catalogue? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, I'm just following the process I usually do for WMS.

[image]

Source:
https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/bec-map/resource/3ec24cb4-f78d-48a9-87e7-516763f00cc8

WMS URL:
https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/WHSE_FOREST_VEGETATION.BEC_BIOGEOCLIMATIC_POLY/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: The important information is in the GetCapabilities response `<MaxScaleDenominator>250000.0</MaxScaleDenominator>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WMS URL works well. After adding the WMS URL, click the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button and see the available information list.

[image]

Then, add the layer you want, however, you need to `zoom in` to some certain level to see the data:

[image]

Comment: That was it thank you! I feel a bit silly I just needed to zoom in to the render scale, its just not a scale I was expecting for this layer.